# Configure TeraTerm to wait for "Enter" key stroke? Or solve PuTTY COM connection error

Tags: serial-port, putty, teraterm

I am using TeraTerm to send strings over COM port using the Serial connection in TeraTerm. I had tried to use PuTTY but it refuses to connect to the COM port and I am not sure why. It says

```
Unable to open connection to COM4
Unable to configure serial port
```

That is neither here nor there, but it does mean that PuTTY like will not be usable for my application.

One thing PuTTY does well, though, is it includes the option for "Local line editing" which means I can make the serial window wait for the "Enter" keystroke before it sends it over COM port. I am looking for a way to make TeraTerm do that as well as right now it sends every character as it is entered into the window.

ie if I type in the word "Test", the window is sending `T/r/n`, `e/r/n`, `s/r/n`, `t/r/n` as opposed to `Test/r/n`

If someone could help me solve this in TeraTerm, or help me fix my PuTTY connection, that would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: If you have the COM port open in TeraTerm, Putty won't be able to open the port.

Comment: *"if I type in the word "Test", the window is sending "T/r/n", "e/r/n", "s/r/n", "t/r/n""* -- I've never seen any terminal emulator do that, and looked at every configuration menu of my copy of TeraTerm.  The program does transmit each character as I type, but there's no (additional) control characters.

Answer (score 1):

When typing characters into TT, the characters are sent out as you type them, and there is no way to configure it otherwise. If anything is sent with each character, this is configurable, but there is no way to configure TT in such a way to "send nothing" until you type 'enter', as other "terminals" do.

Some devices receive the commands in a buffered way and have a short timeout between the characters, so you are never able to "type" a command in TT. For example, many USB devices which use USB-to-serial internals (like ST development tools and MCUs). This is because the USB sends "frames" with each character you type, and the device expects to receive a "full command" in a frame, if the frame is not a valid command, is discarded.

When you type "test", unless you are lightning fast, four frames will be sent. If that is your case, you have to use another terminal program (there are plenty available). If for any reason you are restricted to TT, then you can use the following trick:

write the command in your favorite editor, like PN2, Notepad++, etc., (or even TT itself in a separate terminal, not connected to your target board) copy it with ctrl+c or whatever, and then switch to TT and press either `alt+v` or `alt+r` to send it out without, respective with, a CRLF ending (see the edit menu in TT/VT). The ending can be configured from the setup/terminal menu, and (if enabled in setup/additional_settings/copy_and_paste menu) the mouse's right or mid clicks can be also used.
I usually have a list of commands pre-written, opened in a different window, and instead of typing, the "work" is a sequence of "double click in pn2 window" (to select command), `ctrl+c` (to copy it), "right click in TT window" (to send it out).